# Bundle won't recognize installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rack

I'm trying to run "bundle install --without production" with this as the result:

```
bundle install --without production
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies..............
Using rake 11.2.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Installing rack 2.0.1

Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.0.0
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using puma 3.4.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So multiple times, I have run

```
gem install rack -v 2.0.1
```

with the result:

```
Successfully installed rack-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for rack-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for rack after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I call "rbenv rehash" and retry bundle install and the exact same error message shows up. When I call "ruby -v", it shows I have ruby version 2.3.1. How do I get the bundler to recognize that I have updated Ruby? Is this a problem with Bundler? Am I saving the gems to the wrong place? I have searched similar questions for hours and none of the solutions worked.

Comment: add `ruby 2.3.1` underneath the source in your Gemfile and try bundling again

Comment: I added it like this: 'ruby 2.3.1' but the same error occurred

Comment: do you have a Gemfile.lock? delete that, and bundle install again

Comment: not 100% sure, but i think if you declare your ruby version in your gemfile it should be the format:   ruby "2.3.1"

Comment: @Ren I declared it that way, and it says, "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1"

Comment: @nikkypx I don't have a Gemfile.lock

Comment: yes, @Ren is right, the version should be a string, so it would be `ruby "2.3.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you need Ruby version of 2.2.2 or greater.  Can you check which version you have?  `ruby -v` in the command line should work

EDIT: Looks like you just had to restart your terminal window...

Comment: I have ruby 2.3.1p112

Comment: do you have multiple versions of ruby on your computer? It might be that you haven't set a newer version to default

Comment: I do have multiple versions, but I'm fairly certain that I set the default to 2.3.1 because I ran both "rbenv global 2.3.1" and "rbenv local 2.3.1"

Comment: just to double check can you try 'rbenv versions' in the command line and see which version is active

Comment: 2.3.1 has the star next to it

Comment: how about trying to close your terminal window and open a fresh one.  see if that changes anything